# How to save image from URL fastly in php

Tags: php

I want to save image from live url in php.The fact is that those images are collected by calling `gmap streetview image api`. Within the loop it is being called. Almost 500 iterations are there. But the problem is that it's taking too much time to save.And as per requirement I have to change that. I have used `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` and CURL also, but nothing worked as desired.

So is there any solutions for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Rolling curl class available on github that will help you to save the maximum time cuz this is the fastest way to handle curl request. 
[Get the rolling curl git](https://github.com/chuyskywalker/rolling-curl)

Comment: most welcome @parthachowdhury also if you find something else faster then this then please share that as well.. thanks

Comment: hi ankur can you show me a sample code to save the image using the rolling curl class. Actually i am bit confused that where to put the code for saving file.

Comment: here is the code for you in the new answer m adding

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require 'RollingCurl/RollingCurl.php';
require 'RollingCurl/Request.php';
$urls = array('http://img20.360buyimg.com/da/jfs/t3034/220/2054716322/90888/70d760a9/57d1379dN44824334.jpg','http://img12.360buyimg.com/da/jfs/t3103/216/1194453878/182763/7a8b03d5/57c7d7d4N76ea0c7c.jpg','http://img12.360buyimg.com/da/jfs/t3181/286/1455973725/195103/6ee41941/57ce3452Nc20c284f.jpg');
$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
    # code...
     $rollingCurl->get($urls[$key]);
}
$rollingCurl
    ->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) {
        $saveto = __DIR__.'/images/'.basename($request->getUrl());
        if(file_exists($saveto)){
            unlink($saveto);
        }
        $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
        fwrite($fp, $request->getResponseText());
        fclose($fp);
    })
    ->execute();
;
?>
```

Comment: hi ankur thanks for sharing the code.i have used that.But there is also a problem and that is, the images you took in the the array which have with image name like a.jpg or b.jpg. but i have those image links is like "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=173+Chesterfield+Ind+Blvd+Chesterfield+MO+63005&key=AIzaSyDTn9FYuxm3h3jKbEjwViHb7TKaCsXhUxI"and many more. so there is no image file name and we can not check file existense.Furthermore, from your image links "$request->getResponseText()" giving some binary data but in case of mine its giving nothing.

Comment: or give me some urls to the images

Comment: oh sure here are the links - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=taj%20Mahal&key=AIzaSyDTn9FYuxm3h3jKbEjwViHb7TKaCsXhUxI  && https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=taj%20Mahal&key=AIzaSyDTn9FYuxm3h3jKbEjwViHb7TKaCsXhUxI

Comment: is there any namming convention for the images that you want to follow for the images to be saved... like what if the are saved as 1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on....

Comment: no not at all.i have to just saved the images and get its name accordingly

Comment: OK then give me some time I'll get back to you with some solution

Comment: hi Partha do you have some code that is downloading image from this url... if so than share with me it might save my lots of time

Comment: yes it's normal file_get_contents() & file_put_contents(). $url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url)); but its taking long time to save.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Partha here is the working code use this

```
<?php
require 'RollingCurl/RollingCurl.php';
require 'RollingCurl/Request.php';
$urls = array('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=taj%20Mahal&key=AIzaSyDTn9FYuxm3h3jKbEjwViHb7TKaCsXhUxI');
$cnt = 1;
$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();    
foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
    # code...
     $rollingCurl->get($urls[$key]);
}
$rollingCurl
    ->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) {
        $saveto = __DIR__."/images/".$GLOBALS['cnt'].".jpeg";
        file_put_contents($saveto,$request->getResponseText(),FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
        $GLOBALS['cnt']++;
    })->execute();
?>
```

Comment: hi ankur have you tested that code.on my end it's saving image as "jpeg" extension.but no image viewing at all.may be it's corrupted.

Comment: Yes it will save as jpeg extension.... U can change the extension in `$saveto = __DIR__."/images/".$GLOBALS['cnt'].".jpeg";` this line but it will save all images with same extension....

Comment: actually the images being saved.but windows can not view the image as its empty.it holds 0 bytes.

Comment: U must be running it on localhost... U need to host it on a live server then it will work... I have tested this...

Comment: thanks ankur. yes it did in the live server.thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: Hi ankur again i need your help. Actually all processes related to csv file.it contains more than thousand of records. In every row of the sheet there is address column.By using this addresses i was fetching gmap streetview image from API. Now i have to set every image name according to its address. Previously i made a normal indexed array of addresses which was being used by your given sample code. Now i have changed a bit by making a associative array with addr & file name.So howthe code would be within the "setCallback" scope to get the file name or how will i set the name while requesting.

Comment: However i have solved that problem.Thanks again for your help.

Comment: U cn get the current url by using `request.getUrl()` and there are many other getters defined inside request.php just go thru that